# Error CS0433 The type 'InstanceContext' exists in both 'System.ServiceModel.Duplex, Version=4.0.1.2, ' and 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0'

Tags: uwp, reference, wsdualhttpbinding

Add wcf service with duplex communication in uwp, I need the WSDualHttpBinding class. however the UWP framework will involve the system.servicemodel.primitives. When I add the system.servicemodel, 
Error CS0433 The type 'InstanceContext' exists in both 'System.ServiceModel.Duplex, Version=4.0.1.2, ' and 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0'

What I need is to reference the ystem.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0
how to do

Comment: This may be an error caused by an unknown reference. Please enter the type name completely, just like `System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext`

Comment: it's correct name auto completed by vs.  and I got this error now  CSC : CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.ServiceModel.dll' and 'C:\Users\7540\.nuget\packages\microsoft.netcore.portable.compatibility\1.0.2\ref\netcore50\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Comment: Do you put the UWP project and the WCF project under the same solution? Can you try to separate and start separately?